# Does it matter on which exchange and which currency I buy ETF?

Tags: etf, stock-exchanges, brokerage, european-union, interactive-brokers

I am citizen of EU member state and using Interactive Brokers. I am in for a long time and let's say I am averse to euro, so I focus on US equity ETFs. As EU citizen, I have to buy their UCITS variants. They are often listed on multiple exchanges and in different currencies. For example, VUAA is listed on LSE in GBP and USD, and on XETRA in EUR.

What are the differences I should consider when choosing one of these? In the end, I own desired amount of shares of the same fund, right? So it is only about commissions on different exchanges?
If I send EUR to my brokerage account, should I just use the EUR-denominated one on XETRA to save on currency conversion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should ETF currency risk be avoided by changing denomination or selling in a different currency?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48783/should-etf-currency-risk-be-avoided-by-changing-denomination-or-selling-in-a-dif)

Comment: Also https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124277/is-there-a-currency-risk-in-ucits-etfs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From which Stock Exchange should I buy ETFs?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/145187/from-which-stock-exchange-should-i-buy-etfs)